System.Text.Json could no be load in ssis catalog
I have a problem running an SSIS project developed in VS 2022, compatible with SQL Server 2019. It executes without errors in VS, but after deploying it to SQL Server SSIS catalog, I get an error

System.Text.Json could not be loaded...

I have tried various solutions found online, but I can't get rid of the error. Has anyone encountered such issues?
I included the dependency in app.config as well, but I still get the error.

The proper .dll is probably not installed on the server itself that is why it works locally and not on the server.

Add Your cc# code commented and show which line fails

What solutions have you tried? Please provide the full error message and stack trace if possible.
